# xml:base in JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have some XML like this:

```
<root xml:base="http://www.example.com/foo">
  <childElement someAttribute="bar/blort.html"/>
  <childElement someAttribute="bar/baz/foo.html"/>
</root>
```

The schema for my XML defines someAttribute as being of type xs:anyURI

I want to use JAXB to unmarshall the XML into an object model a bit like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="root")
class Root {
    @XmlElement(name="childElement")
    private List<Child> _children;
}

class Child {
    @XmlAttribute(name="someAttribute")
    private URI _someAttribute;
}
```

I would like values of someAttribute to be resolved according to XML base, i.e. when I unmarshall the XML given above, I want the childrens' attributes to be resolved to java.net.URI instances with values http://www.example.com/foo/bar/blort.html and so on.

I was hoping a custom XmlAdapter would allow me to achieve the right result, but the XmlAdapter has no access to the surrounding context, in particular, the value of xml:base in effect at that point (note that this is not as simple as the most recent enclosing value of xml:base as xml:base can appear anywhere in the tree, and relative xml:bases must be resolved against their ancestors).

I'm using EclipseLink's MOXY implementation of JAXB, if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage an `XMLStreamReader` and an `XmlAdapter` to implement this use case:

**UriAdapter**

The `UriAdapter` is both an `XmlAdapter` for handling the `URI` property, and a `StreamFilter` that we will use to detect the `xml:base` attribute.

```
package forum9906642;

import java.net.URI;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.*;
import javax.xml.stream.*;

public class UriAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, URI> implements StreamFilter {

    private String base = "";

    public UriAdapter() {
    }

    public UriAdapter(String base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    public URI unmarshal(String string) throws Exception {
        return new URI(base + '/' + string);
    }

    public String marshal(URI uri) throws Exception {
        if("".equals(base)) {
            return uri.toString();
        } else {
            URI baseURI = new URI(base);
            return baseURI.relativize(uri).toString();
        }
    }

    public boolean accept(XMLStreamReader reader) {
        if(reader.isStartElement()) {
            String newBase = reader.getAttributeValue("http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace", "base");
            if(null != newBase) {
                base = newBase;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

The code below demonstrates how to use all the pieces together:

```
package forum9906642;

import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.stream.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        UriAdapter uriAdapter = new UriAdapter();

        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader("src/forum9906642/input.xml"));
        xsr = xif.createFilteredReader(xsr, uriAdapter);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setAdapter(uriAdapter);
        Root root = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr);

        for(Child child : root.getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(child.getSomeAttribute().toString());
        }

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setAdapter(uriAdapter);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Child**

```
package forum9906642;

import java.net.URI;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Child {

    @XmlAttribute(name="someAttribute")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(UriAdapter.class)
    private URI _someAttribute;

    public URI getSomeAttribute() {
        return _someAttribute;
    }

    public void setSomeAttribute(URI _someAttribute) {
        this._someAttribute = _someAttribute;
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
http://www.example.com/foo/bar/blort.html
http://www.example.com/foo/bar/baz/foo.html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <childElement someAttribute="bar/blort.html"/>
    <childElement someAttribute="bar/baz/foo.html"/>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks! It needs tweaking slightly to deal with the edge case of the base URL being determined by multiple xml:base attributes on ancestor elements, but this can be done using reader.isEndElement and maintaining a list of xml:bases found at each depth in the tree

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but with nested xml:base (because of `XInclude`), so I ended up having to do this:

```
public class URIFixingUnmarshaller {
  private final JAXBContext jaxb;

  public URIFixingUnmarshaller(JAXBContext jaxb) {
    this.jaxb = jaxb;
  }

  public <T> JAXBElement<T> unmarshal(SAXSource in, Class<T> as)
      throws JAXBException {
    CurrLocation curr = new CurrLocation(in.getXMLReader());
    Unmarshaller u = jaxb.createUnmarshaller();
    u.setListener(new URIUpdater(curr));
    return u.unmarshal(new SAXSource(curr, in.getInputSource()), as);
  }

  private static class CurrLocation extends XMLFilterImpl {
    private Locator curr;

    public CurrLocation(XMLReader actual) {
      setParent(actual);
    }

    @Override
    public void setDocumentLocator(Locator to) {
      super.setDocumentLocator(to);
      this.curr = to;
    }

    String resolve(String uri) {
      try {
        URL base = new URL(curr.getSystemId());
        URL absolute = new URL(base, uri);
        return absolute.toString();
      } catch (MalformedURLException probablyAlreadyAbsolute) {
        return uri;
      }
    }
  }

  private static class URIUpdater extends Unmarshaller.Listener {
    private final CurrLocation curr;

    URIUpdater(CurrLocation curr) {
      this.curr = curr;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterUnmarshal(Object target, Object parent) {
      if (target instanceof SomethingWithRelativeURI) {
        SomethingWithRelativeURI casted = (SomethingWithRelativeURI) target;

        casted.setPath(curr.resolve(casted.getPath()));
      }
    }
  }
}
```